# mat-datepicker has no styling

Tags: angular, angular-material, datepicker, calendar

I have an issue when I want to add mat-datepicker to my project.
Whole project is developed as a package, I dunno if that is important information.

I want to bind mat-datepicker to existing input. mat-datepicker-toggle icon is visible, but when i click it, calendar looks like this:[image: Calendar img]

I have theme scss file added to project and I know it is working, because it affects datepicker-toggle icon.

Can someone figure out what is wrong?

Comment: Do you try to add custom scss for input or for date picker, and can you share with code?